# Browser Rendering Issues

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, rendering

I have noticed a tiny rendering issue across borwsers, and i was wondering if anyone knew how to fix it.

This does not happen when the browser is full screen or maximized but rather only when the browser is resized to a smaller window. I have noticed it on Chrome,Firefox and opera for now.

[image of rendering issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUuCm.jpg)

So what I have here is a nested DIV. 
Here is my Scss code so you can see what I am describing:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>


.parent {
   width: 600px;
   height: 400px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;

   .child{
       width: 100%;
       height: 50px;
       background: #000;
    }
  }
```

You will see in the image there is a small white space between the parent div and child div.

the white space is circled in red.

So does anyone know what causes this minor issue?

Comment: I remember using H1 tags that cause margin issues i tried fixing it with overflow:hidden; but the white space still remained there. its only like half a pixel but it does hurt the eye a bit. also when resizing the browser it only seems to happen on certain pixels

Comment: Show us a minimal working example of your code

Comment: the code example in the question isthe minmal

Comment: I mean can you make a snippet of your code so that we can see where the problem is because your code seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a whitespace in your html between the parent and child. You could test this by removing all whitespace and seeing it if fixes the problem, so instead of this:

```
<div>

   <h1>Title here</h1>

</div>
```

you could try:

```
<div><h1>Title here</h1></div>
```

If this doesn't work, a quick fix might also be to add a 1px negative margin on the child ( `margin-left: -1px`)

Comment: I have tried that as well, this only happens when the browser is resized, there is actually zero whitespace its as if the browser is moving the elements position when it is resizing, but again it is only about 0,5px

Comment: usually when i use a H1 tag i use overflow:hidden; to hide the whites space that is caused by the margins this white space is not the same

Comment: also by adding the negative margin the child will overlap the parent div

Comment: Ok sure. This might help: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/white-space-with-browser-resizing/ I don't think I can help otherwise.